# How can I "un-disable" software in Mojave?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, mojave

I bought a new Macbook Pro, installed Mojave OS, installed drivers for audio hardware / sound card, and the drivers showed up on the list of "disabled software". I've had several talks with Apple & even their engineers weren't really sure how to change this. My issue was sent to their top engineers and I've been told that I will get an answer in several days. I need to record for work now! Any secrets or ideas to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Golden rule for task-critical audio is 'never update until all your DAWs/plugs/interfaces say they're ready'... & then wait another 3 months. I'm aware you can't do this with a brand new Mac... but you're now really in "sit & sweat" territory. I'd be emailing all your essential software makers now, or awaiting their announcements. Your probable only 'fix' would be to borrow an older machine.

Comment: Given that "you bought a mac and *installed Mojave*, I'm going to assume it came with an earlier version of macOS.  Download that, install it and get everything back up and running.

Comment: @Allan - that did occur to me after I'd posted. Get out of jail free card.

Comment: That "golden rule" though...can't be said enough!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I might have to reinstall an earlier version of the OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all traces of a kext?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352579/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-a-kext)