# How to completely remove/uninstall “Disabled Software” from MacOS System Report when a provided uninstall tools + CleanMyMac etc or do not work?

Tags: catalina, macos, software, driver, big-sur

I am having this problem for 5 straight days and tried everything mentioned in various forums without any success (on Catalina 10.15.7). Some help please as I need to completely uninstall/remove this driver which is causing me some problems in running an application.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @mmmmmm Hi there, for some reason this is all I can see from your reply: "How have you tried to uninstall it v"

Comment: It wasn't that much. Just asking for details on how have you tried to uninstall it.

Comment: Tried all of this in this thread without any luck... any ideas? 
 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365911/how-to-remove-disabled-software-from-macos-system-report-when-a-provided-unins/408202#408202

Comment: Hi Joy Jin, thanks for your reply. For both these Terminal commands I write that, then space then drag and drop the app and press Return? Thanks

Comment: Ok noted will do asap and post output here, many thanks!

Comment: @JoyJin I posted the findings on the 2nd screenshot at the top of my thread. "extstat | grep -vi apple" didn't seem to do anything and I can't see the "DJM" driver causing the problem (please see "DJM-450 USBAudio.kext" in the extension library which I just cannot delete/move to trash or do anything with it....

Comment: This driver is not loaded (or kext loading is different in Big Sur), which means that it should not cause problems.

Comment: Drag the file into Terminal and post its path.

Comment: If this file is on the system volume, you can do nothing with it unless you are OK with disabling signed system volume which introduces a bunch more problems. If this file is on the data volume, you should be able to delete it. Perhaps disable SIP or remove it in Recovery OS.

Comment: You can see the path in the screenshot above, in the Pioneer Volume (seperate Volume I reated to install Catalina in order to run the driver which is not compatible with Big Sur). However, whilst on my main Big Sur Volume I found that DJM kext file (from the Pioneer Volume) and managed to delete it completely, and after restarting with Catalina, the File isn't there anymore but still appears as a "Disable Folder"

Comment: Hi Joy Jin, any advice following on from my last? Thanks!

Comment: @JoyJin Hi Joy Jin, any further advice please? Thanks

Comment: @StefD I only have High Sierra machines so I don't know what to do next. But I'm curious to know what problems exactly is caused by this disabled driver?

Comment: Does this answer help you https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352579/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-a-kext