# How to remove Disabled Software in macOS 11?

Tags: macos, big-sur

I found three items in System Report. I've checked `/Library/Extensions/`, `/Library/StagedExtensions` and `/private/var/db/Receipts`. All related files has been deleted. But the three items persist after restarting.

How should I remove them?

OS: macOS 11.1

[image: Three disabled softwares]

Comment: I don't really understand what you seek to do. This shows you software that's been disabled so you have a record of it. If you cleaned up the storage - great - you're set now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all traces of a kext?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352579/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-a-kext)

Answer (score 1):

The System Information.app does retain old information, after the files have been deleted.

I'm not sure whether it maintains its own cache, or uses logs; and not sure how you might 'reset' it.

Comment: I would be upset if Apple purged the list - I need to know what was disabled even after clearing the space. To me, this is the correct behavior and not some cache invalidation issue. This is a record of what happened during a migration step of an upgrade - not a score board to be cleared or "to do list" afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked:

`/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support`

`/Users/<USER>/Library/Caches`

`/Users/<USER>/Library/Containers`

`/Users/<USER>/Library/Preferences`

`/Library/Application Support`

`/Library/Preferences`

Yeah - basically run through the whole `/Users/<USER>/Library` folder, and maybe also the whole `/Library` folder

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I searched the two `Library` with EasyFind and didn't find any trace. Still puzzled now.

Comment: Maybe try to run through the two `Library` folders manually - it should be a more safe way. Look for files with the three names from your screen dump `com.*`

Comment: Still no luck with `sudo find /Library -name "*checkpoint*" -print` etc.