# How to unapprove KEXT system extension on macOS?

Tags: macos, big-sur, kernel-extensions

I am writing docs and need to go through full install many times… once approved, I no longer need to approve KEXT in “Security & Privacy” which makes runs non-reproducible.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I am likely trying to do equivalent of https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/352584/323825 on Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

Boot to recovery mode, mount “Macintosh HD - Data” using “Disk Utility” (to unlock FileVault 2 volume), run following in “Terminal” and hit `ctrl+d` to quit sqlite3.

```
$ /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/sqlite3 /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/SystemPolicyConfiguration/KextPolicy

$ SELECT * FROM kext_policy;

$ DELETE FROM kext_policy WHERE team_id = '8S33FS7Q5Q';

$ SELECT * FROM kext_load_history_v3;

$ DELETE FROM kext_load_history_v3 WHERE team_id = '8S33FS7Q5Q';
```